Regex Replace "__" with "@" in A Selected Capture Group
I have a string that looks like this:
a.*.AGG.all:some__string_here{location=*,username=fred.nurk__nurk.com,testId=12345}

When our application interprets this string, each item with the {} becomes a tag which can be referenced.
Therefore you will have tags for location, username and testId.
Using this regex, (?<=username=)([\w.]+), I can capture fred.nurk__nurk.com in capture group 1.
What I have not been able to figure out is how to then replace the __ in capture group 1 with @.
The end result should see the tag username = fred.nurk@nurk.com
Thank you
PS. If you have a better solution, I would be most appreciative.

Please specify the application that you are using (e.g. Salesforce Desktop Client) and what screen you are on in that application. This will allow us to reference their published documentation for what RegEx engine is in use.

If the application is internal, try to reach out to your support team for details. You could also elaborate on what the application is doing with the RegEx you provide. For example, if the application is is filtering records shown in the browser window, it may just use the browser's RegEx engine. If it is submitted to a server, it probably uses a different RegEx engine.

A few questions though..is there a set format for the username? Like it can not start/end with a dot, can not have double underscores etc..? And do you only want to do a replacement for a match when there are double underscores? Can there be 3 underscores in a row and can the occur multiple times? Does the match have to be between curly braces?

Try:
(?<=username=)((?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]|_(?!_))*)(__)*((?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]|_(?!_))*)

and replacing with:
$1@$2

See: regex101

Explanation
MATCH:

(?<=username=): Anchors to the username field
( ... ): Capture to group 1

(?: ... )*: repeatedly

[a-zA-Z0-9.]: [\w.] but no _
|: or
_(?!_): _ but not two __




(__)*: match __ to group 2
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]|_(?!_))*): To group 3 with same logic as group 1

REPLACE if it is always an E-Mail address:

$1: Keep group 1
@: substitute __ for @
$3: Keep group 2

REPLACE if you can do conditional replacement:

$1: Keep group 1
${2:+@:}: substitute group 2, when set with @ else leave blank
$3: Keep group 2


@Thefourthbird thanks for pointing this out. This could be handled with conditional replacement if that is permitted; see here

Although that has limited support, in this case it could still add an @ to the end of the string if there is nothing following the double underscores but that would be nitpicking. But as you are using capture group 1 in the replacement, you don't need the leading positive lookbehind at all, you can just include that in the group. Then you might also repeat the first character class and overall decrease the number of steps https://regex101.com/r/G6fTjH/1

@Thefourthbird Thank you for nitpicking - learning is what I am here for ^^. My general "philosophy" is to keep as much of the OP regex in tact so that it will be more lexible for them in the future, but point well taken!

It depends on which language you're using. For example, in python:
import re
st = "a.*.AGG.all:some__string_here{location=*,username=fred.nurk__nurk.com,testId=12345}"
print(re.sub(r"(?<=username=)([\w.]+)", lambda m: m.group(1).replace("__", "@"), st))

Result:
a.*.AGG.all:some__string_here{location=*,username=fred.nurk@nurk.com,testId=12345}



@jatsad With which language are you coding?

I am using regex within our application, so not using a programming language.

@jatsad Read their docs. Often, this might work: Replace $1 with @.
